Find an unknown length formed by various segments drawn through the incircle
Question: Triangle $ABC$ has incircle $\omega$ tangent to $AB$, $BC$, and $CA$ at points $F$, $D$, and $E$ respectively. Segment $AD$ intersects segment $EF$ and circle $\omega$ at points $P$ and $Q \neq D$, respectively. $EF$ intersects the extension of side $BC$ at a point $X$. If $PE=5$ and $PF=12$, find $QX$.

Honestly, I'm completely stuck here. I tried to "fakesolve" the question by assuming some lengths for $AP$ and $PD$, but later found that doing so created contradictions later. I also attempted to coordinate bash, but that got pretty messy pretty quickly.
The only idea I have here is that the directions say that the question set where this came from "has at least one harmonic problem", but I have no idea if that applies here.

Could construct it in Geogebra or other geometry software?

@Narasimham I would like to know how to do it rigorously

Is there any information about the point $D$? Like it's the midpoint or what?

This is indeed a problem about harmonic points. We can solve it in a geometric way.
Firstly $[E,F;Q,D]$ is harmonic set because $AE,AF$ are tangent to the circle. Thus the lines $[DD,DQ;DE,DF]$ is harmonic. By projecting to line $EF$ we see $[X,P;E,F]$ is harmonic.
If we set $EX=x$ this shows $\frac{x+17}{x}=\frac{12}{5}$, so $x=\frac{85}{7}$. The harmonic set also shows $XQ$ is tangent to the circle. Finally $$QX=\sqrt{QE\cdot QF}=\sqrt{\frac{17340}{49}}=\frac{34}{7}\sqrt{15}$$

This answer uses coordinate geometry.
Let $P(0,0),E(-5,0),F(12,0)$.
Let $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ (where $b\gt 0$) be the equation of $\omega$.
Since $E,F$ are on $\omega$, we have
$$(-5-a)^2+b^2=r^2\tag1$$
$$(12-a)^2+b^2=r^2\tag2$$
$(1)-(2)$ gives $a=\frac 72$ and $r^2=b^2+\frac{289}{4}$.
The point $A$ is the intersection point of $AC$ : $y=\frac{\frac 72+5}{-b}(x+5)$ with $AB$ : $y=\frac{\frac 72-12}{-b}(x-12)$, so we get $A(\frac 72, \frac{-289}{4b})$.
The points $D,Q$ are the intersection points of $\omega$ : $(x-\frac 72)^2+(y-b)^2=b^2+\frac{289}{4}$ with $AP$ : $y=\frac{-289}{14b}x$, so we get $D(\frac{-14bc_+}{289},c_+)$ and $Q(\frac{-14bc_-}{289},c_-)$ where
$$c_{\pm}= \frac{578(120b\pm 17 \sqrt{60b^2 + 4335})}{196 b^2 + 83521}$$
The point $X$ is the intersection point of $BC$ : $y-c_+=\frac{\frac 72+\frac{14bc_+}{289}}{c_+-b}(x+\frac{14bc_+}{289})$ with $x$-axis, so $X(d,0)$ where
$$d=-\frac{14bc_+}{289}-\frac{c_+(c_+-b)}{\frac 72+\frac{14bc_+}{289}}$$
So, we get
$$\begin{align}QX^2&=\bigg(d+\frac{14bc_-}{289}\bigg)^2+(0-c_-)^2
\\\\&=\bigg(\frac{14b(c_--c_+)}{289}-\frac{c_+(c_+-b)}{\frac 72+\frac{14bc_+}{289}}\bigg)^2+(0-c_-)^2
\\\\&=\bigg(\frac{-3332 b \sqrt{60 b^2 + 4335} - 68\times 147390}{7 (196 b^2 + 83521)}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{578(120b-17 \sqrt{60b^2 + 4335})}{196 b^2 + 83521}\bigg)^2
\\\\&=\frac{17340}{49}\end{align}$$
Therefore, we finally obtain
$$\color{red}{QX=\dfrac{34\sqrt{15}}{7}}$$
